# using rigidBody and CharacterControll together in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

is it possible to use them both at the same time so one would provide gravity and the other controls when creating a player without side effect? I tried searching in google and (you tube) but found nothing.
**strong text**

Comment: Curious what "without side effects" is referring to?

Comment: like killing performance or disabling some important features of the game object

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if adding both rigidbody and charactercontroller would work, but it's way easier, less buggy and less expensive to just code your own gravity. Here is a little example of my gravity system with a isGrounded check:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerMovScript : MonoBehaviour
{   public float gravity = -9.81f; // change this for faster falling
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f; // maximal distance between ground and your character for gravity to reset
    public bool isGrounded;

    public CharacterController Controller;
    public Transform GroundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundMask; // make sure to set any objects that should act as things you want your gravity to reset on to this layer
    public Vector3 velocity;

    void Update()
    {
    
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(GroundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask); // Make a sphere to check if you are grounded


        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f; // set velocity.y to -2f if vel.y is less than 0 because 0 is sometimes buggy
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        Controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        }
}
```

EDIT: If you are gonna use this, don't just copy and paste it, you won't learn anything, try to optimize it, and rewrite it to your liking.